# sql missing rows when grouped by DAY, MONTH, YEAR

Tags: t-sql, date, grouping

If I select from a table group by the month, day, year, 
it only returns rows with records and leaves out combinations without any records, making it appear at a glance that every day or month has activity, you have to look at the date column actively for gaps. How can I get a row for every day/month/year, even when no data is present, in T-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51836/clark) got back to me with this code, underscores converted to dashes because StackOverflow was mangling underscores -- no numbers table required. Our example is complicated a bit by a join to another table, but maybe the code example will help someone someday.

```
declare @career-fair-id int 
select @career-fair-id = 125

create table #data ([date] datetime null, [cumulative] int null) 

declare @event-date datetime, @current-process-date datetime, @day-count int 
select @event-date = (select careerfairdate from tbl-career-fair where careerfairid = @career-fair-id) 
select @current-process-date = dateadd(day, -90, @event-date) 

    while @event-date <> @current-process-date 
    begin 
    select @current-process-date = dateadd(day, 1, @current-process-date) 
    select @day-count = (select count(*) from tbl-career-fair-junction where attendanceregister <= @current-process-date and careerfairid = @career-fair-id) 
        if @current-process-date <= getdate() 
        insert into #data ([date], [cumulative]) values(@current-process-date, @day-count) 
    end 

    select * from #data 
    drop table #data
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a calendar table and outer join on that table

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a [numbers table](http://andre-silva-cardoso.blogspot.com/2007/11/sql-trickspatterns-1-numbers-table.html).  While it can be hackish, it's the best method I've come by to quickly query missing data, or show all dates, or anything where you want to examine values within a range, regardless of whether all values in that range are used.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what SQLMenace said, you can use a CROSS JOIN to quickly populate the table or efficiently create it in memory.
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=562806

Answer (score 0):

The task calls for a complete set of dates to be left-joined onto your data, such as

`DECLARE    @StartInt   int

DECLARE    @Increment  int

DECLARE    @Iterations int



SET    @StartInt   = 0

SET    @Increment = 1

SET    @Iterations = 365





SELECT

      tCompleteDateSet.[Date]

      ,AggregatedMeasure = SUM(ISNULL(t.Data, 0))

FROM

                       (


                             SELECT 

                                       [Date] = dateadd(dd,GeneratedInt, @StartDate)

                             FROM 

                                       [dbo].[tvfUtilGenerateIntegerList] (

                                                          @StartInt, 

                                                         ,@Increment, 

                                                         ,@Iterations

                                                 )

                         )       tCompleteDateSet

     LEFT JOIN           tblData t

                  ON      (t.[Date] = tCompleteDateSet.[Date])

GROUP BY

    tCompleteDateSet.[Date]`

where the table-valued function tvfUtilGenerateIntegerList is defined as

`-- Example Inputs



-- DECLARE @StartInt   int 

-- DECLARE @Increment  int

-- DECLARE @Iterations int

-- SET @StartInt   = 56200

-- SET @Increment = 1

-- SET @Iterations = 400

-- DECLARE @tblResults TABLE 

--  (

--       IterationId int identity(1,1),

--       GeneratedInt    int

-- )





-- =============================================

-- Author:     6eorge Jetson

-- Create date: 11/22/3333

-- Description:    Generates and returns the desired list of integers as a table

-- =============================================

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvfUtilGenerateIntegerList]

(

     @StartInt   int, 

     @Increment  int,

      @Iterations int

) 

RETURNS 

@tblResults TABLE 

(

     IterationId int identity(1,1),

     GeneratedInt    int

)

AS

BEGIN



      DECLARE @counter int 

      SET @counter= 0

      WHILE (@counter < @Iterations)

         BEGIN

         INSERT @tblResults(GeneratedInt) VALUES(@StartInt + @counter*@Increment)

         SET @counter = @counter + 1

         END




      RETURN 

END

--Debug

--SELECT * FROM @tblResults`