# Can I use recursion in a Sql Server 2005 View?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I tried to use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` in a view to generate a list of dates.
This seems to be unsupported. Is there a workaround for this issue?

EDIT to Explain what I actually want to do:

I have 2 tables.

table1: int weekday, bool available

table2: datetime date, bool available

I want the result:
view1: date (here all days in this year), available(from table2 or from table1 when not in table2).

That means I have to apply a join on a date with a weekday.
I hope this explanation is understandable, because I actually use more tables with more fields in the query.

I found this code to generate the recursion:

```
WITH Dates AS
(
    SELECT cast('2008-01-01' as datetime) Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date + 1
    FROM    Dates   
    WHERE   Date + 1 < DATEADD(yy, 1, GETDATE())
)
```

Comment: I solved the problem by creating an extra table in the database with the date and the dayofweek as columns. I set the millenium bug at 2037 for the next developer at that time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=124653) - if you can find a way to do it within 100 levels of recusion (have a table of numbers), which will get you to within 100 recursion levels, you'll be able to do it.  But if you have a numbers or pivot table, you won't need the recursion anyway...

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers) (but I would create a table and not a table-valued function), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456/sql-missing-rows-when-grouped-by-day-month-year) and [this link](http://andre-silva-cardoso.blogspot.com/2007/11/sql-trickspatterns-1-numbers-table.html) and [this link](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/94376/sql_server_94376.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CTE](http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2007/09/06/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2005---CTE-Example-of-a-simple.aspx) for hierarchical queries.

Comment: This is CTE or am I missing something?

Comment: That is a CTE, but the recursion level is limited to 100 in a view (or earlier, if the recursion terminates naturally with some criteria in the CTE).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
;WITH CTE_Stack(IsPartOfRecursion, Depth, MyDate) AS
(
    SELECT 
         0 AS IsPartOfRecursion
        ,0 AS Dept 
        ,DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST('01.01.2012' as datetime))  AS MyDate 
    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
         1 AS IsPartOfRecursion 
        ,Parent.Depth + 1 AS Depth 
        --,DATEADD(DAY, 1, Parent.MyDate) AS MyDate
        ,DATEADD(DAY, 1, Parent.MyDate) AS MyDate
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 0 AS Nothing 
    ) AS TranquillizeSyntaxCheckBecauseWeDontHaveAtable 

    INNER JOIN CTE_Stack AS Parent 
        --ON Parent.Depth < 2005 
        ON DATEADD(DAY, 1, Parent.MyDate) < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, CAST('01.01.2012' as datetime)) 
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_Stack 
WHERE IsPartOfRecursion = 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 367) -- Accounting for leap-years
;
```

Comment: This is not valid inside a view which is the point of the question. The hint needs to go in the select from the view.