# SQL Server Showing Zero count

Tags: sql-server

I have one table which is my stocks stored and I have another table which is stock order stores , now I want to get current week records count from Stock table based on inquiry table date.

Query works fine for me except some days is no records but I want to show zero also.

```
   select datename(dw,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(HOUR, 11, inquiry_tbl.order_date)))) date
,      count(stock_id) as TotalShipment
from      stock_tbl  
left join inquiry_tbl on stock_tbl.Inquiry_id = inquiry_tbl.Inquiry_id
where stock_tbl.inquiry_id = inquiry_tbl.inquiry_id
    and DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(HOUR, 11, inquiry_tbl.order_date)))
    >=
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,DATEADD(HOUR, 11, getdate())), -2)
    and
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(HOUR, 11, inquiry_tbl.order_date)))
    <=
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,DATEADD(HOUR, 11, getdate())), 4)
group by DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(HOUR, 11, inquiry_tbl.order_date)))
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove `stock_tbl.inquiry_id = inquiry_tbl.inquiry_id` from your where clause. it will eliminate rows that would otherwise be included - it effectively changes your left outer join to an inner join:

edit: I just realized you're grouping by the column that is being left-joined in. In that case, your join is backwards as well. Try this:

edit: From your comment I'm assuming that there is no row in either table for the missing dates. In that case you must introduce those days into your query - here's an example of doing it with a `values` statement, you may want to consider using a date table if performance is an issue:

```
declare @start_date datetime = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, DATEADD(HOUR, 11, getdate())), -2)

select
    week.day date,
    count(stock_id) as TotalShipment
from
    (select DATEADD(dd, d, @start_date) day
     from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) x(d)) week
left join
    inquiry_tbl on inquiry_tbl.order_date between week.day and week.day + 1
left join
    stock_tbl on stock_tbl.Inquiry_id = inquiry_tbl.Inquiry_id
group by
    week.day
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "inquiry_tbl.inquiry_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "inquiry_tbl.order_date" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "inquiry_tbl.order_date" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "inquiry_tbl.order_date" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "inquiry_tbl.order_date" could not be bound.

Comment: It's redundant but I'm not sure if it causes a problem.

Comment: @VahidND it will eliminate rows that would otherwise be included from the left join - it effectively changes the left outer join to an inner join.

Comment: @ShaahinRoshan that error message should not result from changing your where clause. let me clarify my answer with what the entire query should be

Comment: @gordy Same Result only getting two days instead of 7days

Comment: @gordy You're right I thought it is an inner join which is not.

Comment: @ShaahinRoshan you'll need to introduce the rows for the missing days from another table. I've edited my answer with one way you could do it

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's not an elegant solution to this, but one possible solution is creating a Date table which have the rows for every day so you can join your result with that table. Another solution can be creating a Stored Procedure which return the week rows for a specified date range.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456/sql-missing-rows-when-grouped-by-day-month-year) and [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2800/sql-server-function-to-return-a-range-of-dates/).

Comment: Same result only two days 

Saturday 12
Sunday 12

Comment: Thanks for your efforts , I got solution.